# Regarding group by inside inner join mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying the below group by inside inner join in mysql. It's saying unknown column name.  Could You please help me out regarding this. I am getting an error on this query "SELECT Min(Id) FROM testinbcalls group by lc.DBID"  in the inner join saying "Unknown column name DBID in the groupby).   Is there an alternative way I can modify this query if groupby is not allowed.  I tried ""SELECT Min(Id) FROM testinbcalls WHERE Id= lc.DBID" instead of group by but it didn't work.  I prefer not  move the check to the where clause as i want the records to be filtered on the inner join itself.  Could anyone help me out.  Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT ic.Id as `Id`,  lc.DBID,
init.Name as Init,
lc.TargetNumber as PhoneNumber, 
CONCAT(us.FirstName,' ',us.Surname) as UserName,
 iout.Name as Outc FROM 
 testcalls ic
 INNER JOIN testinit init on ic.InitId=init.Id
 INNER JOIN users us on ic.UserId=us.Id
 INNER JOIN testinbcalls lc ON ic.Id=lc.CallId AND  lc.DBID IS NOT NULL AND  ic.Id=(**SELECT Min(Id) FROM testinbcalls group by lc.DBID** )
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(Id) Id FROM  testinbcalls  group by lc.DBID) mincallid ON ic.Id=mincallid.Id
 INNER JOIN icomes iout on ic.OutId=iout.Id 
 WHERE ic.AssignedDateTime between '2015-06-08 00:00:00' and '2015-06-09 23:59:59' ORDER BY Id DESC limit 250;
```

Answer (score 0):

You change it to below removing the table alias `lc`. With that you are actually referring the outer query table.

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(Id) AS MinId FROM  testinbcalls  group by DBID)
```

Comment: Thx for the info . But I need to  check ic.Id= MIN(Id) to restrict the rows

Comment: You can do that like `ic.Id=(SELECT Min(Id) FROM testinbcalls group by DBID )`